# Migrating to Wordpress from Zen Cart

Tags: woocommerce

Im currently managing https://www.clippertea.com.sg/

The site is currently managed by a developer on Zen Cart and hosted on Rackspace.

Due to slow response and generally incompetency and high cost, we decided to manage both the website and the webshop on our own.

There are 2 things we need to do:

1) Migrating https://www.clippertea.com.sg/ to another host and preserving the original design (as an information site)

2) After migration when visitor click on "Shop", it will direct it to the NEW wordpress woocommerce storefront. (as an online shop using woocommerce)

In short, under new host of goDaddy (previously Rackspace), we will have www.clippertea.com.sg with its current existing look and clicking on "Shop" will lead to the woocommerce plugin as our online shop.

Is it possible to do so? (Under WP, one main website for information and clicking on "Shop" category leads to our webshop using Woocommerce)

Do I need another developer to migrate all the content from old site to new site? Or can I do so myself easily.

Comment: It will be very hard to answer your question, since we don't know what your skill-set is. Have you done any programming before, WordPress development? Have you worked with WooCommerce?

Comment: In terms of using wordpress as a blog and managing CMS I'm familiar with that. Just confused about the whole migration process where everything is now hosted under goDaddy and preserving the original design and URL structure.

Comment: I think you probably will need someone to help you. There are plugins that migrate Zen Cart to WooCommerce, but I find that big moves like that rarely go smoothly... You could try doing it first locally (look into WAMP or MAMP), and then decide if you need someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a "shop" folder where you can upload WordPress and install WooCommerce there.